# Strange crash with AppCompat, Vectors and 4.1.2

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I get a very strange crash being reported when I try and run my app on Android v4.1.2 (API 16).  The following error I get on older phones:

```
07-10 16:15:52.188 5496-5496/com.amplified.music.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amplified.music.debug/com.amplified.music.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageButton
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageButton
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
          at com.amplified.music.fragment.PlayerFragment.onCreateView(PlayerFragment.java:233)
          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
          at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreateView(RoboFragmentActivity.java:163)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
          at com.amplified.music.activity.RoboAppCompatActivity.setContentView(RoboAppCompatActivity.java:55)
          at com.amplified.music.activity.MainActivity.onAuthenticatedCustomer(MainActivity.java:87)
          at com.amplified.music.activity.MusicActivity.onCreate(MusicActivity.java:72)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/color/abc_primary_text_material_dark.xml"
          at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
          at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
          at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
```

I'm using vectors with the `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` setting turned on in my gradle build file.  I'm referring to my images using the following code:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/playQueueButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Button.Flat.Inverse"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_queue_music_black_24dp"/>
```

My style is defined as following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Flat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:tint">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button.Flat.Inverse" parent="AppTheme.Button.Flat">
    <item name="android:tint">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/home_button_selector</item>
</style>
```

I can't find any details online about this error.  I'm not sure why it's crashing.

Comment: It looks like the underlying cause is a NumberFormatException. It seems that android has had issues with parsing svgs on certain API versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561170/vectordrawable-causes-numberformatexception and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202670. Could you see if the solutions outlined in the SO post and google code issue help you out?

Comment: Well it's the fact it's having trouble with something clearly inside the App Compat styles.  One thing I didn't include was I refactored my previous style that didn't inherit from the AppCompat style.  That worked on API 16.  Yes it's a NumberFormatException, but notice what it's trying to parse.   Why didn't the SDK replace that with the proper integer?  I actually know answer though.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for the info and good point about it error-ing out while parsing a color resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chubbsondubs seems like you can only apply tint to drawables from 5.0 and above? here's the document [Official Android document]

[1]https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html

Comment: Sounds like that may have been the issue after all, but the platform never complained about using it.  Normally if I try and use an API, attribute, etc  that isn't supported in my minSDK Android Studio complains about it.  In this case it never complained.

Comment: If you feel this is correct answer please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error and it seemed that "?android:textColorPrimary" may not be defined in some old systems.

My Solution:
 1. Define textColorPrimary in my own color.xml
 2. Change "?android:textColorPrimary" to "@color/textColorPrimary"

The drawable could be tinted no matter Vector or not in my Android 4.2.2 mobile

Answer (score 0):

So I never figured out why Android is throwing this error.  After all the SDK tools should've replaced the @color reference with a proper integer from R class.  So what's the heck is happening?

Turns out it didn't like the use of the tint property in the style.  If removed tint and replaced my vector drawable with a vector with the right color viola it worked.  So it was hard to find out if tint was supported or not on API 16, but it sounded like tint was partially "supported", but not fully on API 16.

I was using tint property before and it was working, but it was not inheriting from that AppCompat style.  It only had this problem using tint + AppCompat.  So this is a problem between AppCompat + tint property, and not the tint property in general.

Comment: question,  when you are changing tint of vector drawable are you using VectorCompat to load the drawable? if you are manually try to load svgs in your code for say applying tint then you gotta use VectorCompat

Comment: These vectors were referenced using app:srcCompat attribute in the XML.

Comment: see my answer, as per the documents you may only apply tint on drawables ( bitmap, vector etc.) 5.x and upwards.

Comment: Sure this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202670 is not your problem?